# RSA re-encryption scheme

Tags: rsa, public-key

Is there such an algorithm that would allow to upgrade the encryption of an RSA-encrypted message without revealing the plaintext to the untrusted user?

Basically, such an algorithm would probably be split in two parts.

1. The algorithm would take the **old private key** and the **new public key** and generate a sort of **intermediate key**.
2. The key would then be distributed to untrusted parties who could upgrade their encrypted messages to the new keypair using the **intermediate key** and (maybe) the **new public key**.

Neither the **old private key** nor the **new private key** should not be easily recoverable (computationaly infeasible) from the intermediate key, so untrusted parties wouldn't be able to recover the plaintext.

Now I suppose that such a scheme does not exist, because I don't see a real use case for it, but it would be interesting to know if such a thing can be done.

Comment: This is called proxy re-encryption and there are a lot of ways of doing it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_re-encryption

Comment: Section 4.3 of this paper has an example for RSA but it is unidirectional: www.isoc.org/isoc/conferences/ndss/03/proceedings/papers/14.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As PulpSpy have mentioned, It is called proxy re-encryption. A company called NyCypher have implemented it but with secp251 keys https://blog.nucypher.com/proxy-re-encryption-playground-in-python-3bc66170b9bf. 
Other option is charm-crypto,https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/tree/2.7-master